# Can node JS replace Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

Hi I'm using **Ajax** call in my **Spring MVC** project to fetch data and dynamically bind it using **Javascript**. Now I am curious whether can I use **Node.js** as an alternative(provide a link) and if not, are there any alternatives.

Comment: Why you need an alternative, what is wrong with AJAX?

Comment: @ianaya89  thers is nothing wrong with AJAX,I heard that node.js is very fast so i  thought of this possibbilty .

Comment: Yes, node is great but is server side javascript. I highly recommend it but you in this case you need to consider migrate your back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Node.js** is a server side platform which use the `JavaScript` language (similar JAVA). So the answer is NO. You can not replace an AJAX call with Node.js

You could replace JAVA with it if you want :)

Answer (score 0):

No. Node.js is a server-side, so you will still need to make client-side ajax calls to get data dynamically to the browser.